# What is the difference between these two verbs "Joindre" and "Rejoindre" ?

Tags: grammaire

For example, When I want to say:

*I have joined a company X.*

*J'ai rejoint une entreprise X.*

Why we are using the "rejoindre" verb not "joindre", here? When to use each of these verbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Joindre* means to connect two entities, to make them touch/communicate/act together.

> *Joindre les deux bouts.* To make end meet.
>
> *Joindre l'utile à l'agréable.* To mix business with pleasure.

*Rejoindre* means either to reconnect things that were disconnected before or to move toward and reach someone/something.

The meaning is sometimes equivalent:

> *Venez nous rejoindre !* Come and join us!
>
> *Venez vous joindre à nous !* Come and join us!

but sometimes, it is clearly different. Compare:

> *Je n'ai pas réussi à le joindre* : I was unable to reach him (because he didn't pick up the phone).
>
> *Je n'ai pas réussi à le rejoindre* : I was unable to reach him (because I was too slow).